# How can I verify that MySQL's slave_compressed_protocol is working

Tags: mysql, replication

I've set [slave_compressed_protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_compressed_protocol)=1 on both my master and slave.

Using SHOW VARIABLES, I can see that it's set.

How can I check that it's actually working?

Answer (score 3):

## [Connection Phase of the Client/Server Protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase.html)

[image: The Connection Phase of the Client/Server Protocol]

At the Client Response, there is [crosscheck of capabilities between the client and the server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/capability-flags.html). The [**CLIENT_COMPRESS flag (value 0x00000020) needs to be mutually exchanged**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html#section-compression) before continuing authentication.

To be honest with you, I have never heard of a MySQL question this deep. Good the thing all of this appears in the MySQL Internals Documentation.

How on earth would you actually know where to intercept the CLIENT_COMPRESS ?

I would suggest using [**tcpdump**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/tcpdump-command-examples/) or [**snort**](http://www.snort.org/) to inspect packets.

I will leave it to you to read up on the needed exchange packets

- [Protocol::Handshake](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::Handshake)
- [Protocol::HandshakeResponse](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeResponse)

Answer (score 2):

`slave_compressed_protocol = 1` is only required on the slave to notify the master that it wants to use the compression.

I use `iftop -P` to verify it's actually working. For example,

**Disable compression, restart MySQL and monitor it on the slave:**

root@slave # vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
slave_compressed_protocol = 0
```

root@slave # systemctl restart mysql.service

root@slave # mysql -e "SHOW variables WHERE variable_name REGEXP 'slave_compressed_protocol';"

```
| slave_compressed_protocol | OFF    |
```

root@slave # iftop -P

```
TOTAL:                  8.90MB
```

**Run the insert query 1000 times on the master:**

exp.student schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Intro` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

root@master # vim bench.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

longStr=$(printf 'asdf %d ' {1..1000})

for i in {1..1000}; do
        mysql -e "INSERT INTO exp.student (Name, Age, Intro) VALUES ('Jun ${i}', 15, '${longStr}');"
done
```

root@master # bash bench.bash

**Enable compression, restart MySQL, do the above steps again and compare the total transfer result:**

root@slave # vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
slave_compressed_protocol = 1
```

root@slave # systemctl restart mysql.service

root@slave # mysql -e "SHOW variables WHERE variable_name REGEXP 'slave_compressed_protocol';"

```
| slave_compressed_protocol | ON    |
```